# How to unnest_longer or equivalent on multiple columns at once

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have the following tibble; it contains sequences of numbers, the index values of the sequences, and the seed that produced the sequences.

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Rowwise: 
    seed sequence   max_val n_steps step_index
   <int> <list>       <dbl>   <int> <list>    
 1     1 <int [1]>        1       1 <int [1]> 
 2     2 <dbl [2]>        2       2 <int [2]> 
 3     3 <dbl [8]>       16       8 <int [8]> 
 4     4 <dbl [3]>        4       3 <int [3]> 
 5     5 <dbl [6]>       16       6 <int [6]> 
 6     6 <dbl [9]>       16       9 <int [9]> 
 7     7 <dbl [17]>      52      17 <int [17]>
 8     8 <dbl [4]>        8       4 <int [4]> 
 9     9 <dbl [20]>      52      20 <int [20]>
10    10 <dbl [7]>       16       7 <int [7]>
```

I am trying to turn it into long format to plot all sequences at once using ggplot. The new tibble should look like this:

```
  seed step_index values
1    1          1      1 # start of sequence 1
2    2          1      2 # start of sequence 2
3    2          2      1 
4    2          3      3 # start of sequence 3
5    2          4     10
6    3          1      5
... (etc.)
```

I discovered `tidyr`'s `unnest()` functions, and thought they were promising, but I can't seem to figure out how to unnest multiple variables at once, and running multiple `unnest_longer()` commands in series like this

```
collatz_sequences <- collatz_data %>% 
  select(seed, sequence, step_index) %>%
  
  unnest_longer(sequence) %>% unnest_longer(step_index) %>% #TODO: FIND SOMETHING THAT DOES THIS PROPERLY
  
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(step_index, seed), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>% 
  select(-variable) %>% 
  arrange(seed)

collatz_sequences
```

produces the following wrong tibble, which contains repeated values:

```
# A tibble: 949 × 3
    seed step_index values
   <int>      <int>  <dbl>
 1     1          1      1
 2     2          1      2
 3     2          2      2
 4     2          1      1
 5     2          2      1
 6     3          1      3
 7     3          2      3
 8     3          3      3
 9     3          4      3
10     3          5      3
# … with 939 more rows
```

How can I avoid these repeated values and get the intended long format tibble?

Comment: I think you need to have `unnest(c(sequence, step_index))` (assuming both columns have the same lengths

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment! Worked perfectly right away!